# Binding scrollTop directly in template gives error

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 5 project. In my project I have chat box like element. I am listing the comments in a `ul`, its height is fixed with `overflow-y: auto`. Like a standard chat box I have to show the very bottom of this scrollable `ul`. So when a new comment is added it will be coming at the bottom of the `ul` and I have to scroll to the bottom. In order to achieve this I am binding the `scrollTop` property of this `ul` to the `scrollHeight` as follows,

```
<ul class="comment-list" #commentEl [scrollTop]="commentEl.scrollHeight">
    <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">{{ comment }}</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting an error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '851'. Current value: '0'` while initializing this component and destroying this component. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the *ul* tag in a div element and reference the DOM using `viewChild` decorator.

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:200px;width:100%;overflow-y:auto" #commentEl [scrollTop]="scrolltop">
    <ul class="comment-list">
        <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">{{ comment }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('commentEl') comment: ElementRef;  
scrolltop: number = null;
```

And give where you add the comments

```
this.scrolltop = this.comment.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
```

demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ranet6-m9pp7j?file=app%2Ftest1%2Ftest1.component.ts)

Comment: This approach will not solve the error. This is same as my code. The only difference is that you wrapped the element in a div. I tried your solution. But the error still exists

Comment: do you checked the demo link. Can i know what exactly you need I think i misunderstand you

Comment: Scrolling to the bottom is working fine. But please have a look at the question again. When the component is destroyed I am getting an error as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: can i know how your component is created and destroyed. Whether it is dynamic component

Comment: This component is called inside an Angular Material tab. The component is initialized when the corresponding tab is active and destroyed when moved to another tab.

Comment: i updated what you said can you check with this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ranet6-m9pp7j?file=app%2Ftest1%2Ftest1.component.html)

Comment: Thank you soo much... initially when the page gets rendered... the data was undefined. So, my solution to fix that was `setTimeout`

Comment: can someone help me here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279766/angular-error-ng0100-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-everytime-i-sc

Comment: can someone help me here ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279766/angular-error-ng0100-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-everytime-i-sc