# Angular Error NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError everytime i scroll

Tags: angular, typescript

So i'm building a chat app, everytime you send a message you will automatically scrolled to the bottom, and i use this code to do that

`.html`

```
<div class="chatContent" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
```

`.ts`

```
    @ViewChild('scrollMe') scrollMe;
    this.shouldScroll = this.scrollMe.scrollTop + this.scrollMe.clientHeight ===this.scrollMe.scrollHeight;
             if (!this.shouldScroll) {
               this.scrollToBottom();
             }
        
  scrollToBottom() {
    this.scrollMe.scrollTop = this.scrollMe.scrollHeight;
  }
```

and this error appear

[image]

i've seen this post [Binding scrollTop directly in template gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869566/binding-scrolltop-directly-in-template-gives-error) but still got that error after i refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

Add detect change method so update DOM value.

import the  `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Also add in `constructor`

```
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Then add in your method when update scroll value.

```
 scrollToBottom() {
    this.scrollMe.scrollTop = this.scrollMe.scrollHeight;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: thanks! i implemented this solution already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513421/ngif-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked similar tho, but he said that it only appears on dev mode